# MySQL Innodb Full text Proximity Search Gives Horrible Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, full-text-search, innodb

I have a mysql database with a simple table named item.  Item contains the following fields and has 55,000 records:

ID (PK)
Description (INNODB FULL TEXT)
DATE

By design i am forced to index all the way down to 1 character words since some descriptions contain names such as Item 1 a 2 42  where the spaces MUST be kept intact.  I am running a full text search against this table and here are my results for the following code:

```
Select ID, Description, Date
From Item
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MONTH)
AND description LIKE CONCAT('%item 1 2 a 4%')
AND MATCH (description) AGAINST ('+item +1 +2 +a +4' in boolean mode);
```

This Query returns in 1.2 seconds.  However, once i add the following proximity search to the query my return time goes through the roof:

```
Select ID, Description, Date
From Item
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MONTH)
AND description LIKE ('%item%')
AND MATCH (description) AGAINST ('+item +1 +2 +a +4' in boolean mode)
AND MATCH (description) AGAINST ('"1 2 a 4" @30' in boolean mode);
```

This Query returns in **54 seconds!**  The proximity search is a must to my query since i need to make sure i find "item 1 2 a" and not "item 1 2 48884848 222 a" which would be totally different. Proximity search runs a lot better when the words are more than 1 characters, but there are some circumstances that would call for a user typing in 1 character words.  Is there ANYTHING else i can do that would be an alternative to proximity searching of full-text innodb but have much better performance?  If there is nothing else in MYSQL, i am open to using something to integrate to give me a better proximity search (i am on windows though).

thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `LIKE` condition defeats your full-text indexes. Replace the condition

```sql
description LIKE CONCAT('%item 1 2 a 4%') -- and why CONCAT() anyways?
```

... with

```sql
MATCH (description) AGAINST ('"item 1 2 a 4"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Your second condition is useless as it overlaps with the first condition (you have already filtered by the exact string "item 1 2 a 4", these rows always match '+item +1 +2 +a +4').

Comment: I have fixed the concat in the example above, i pass in some variables to the routine so that is why i had it there.  Your second example would not replace the proximity search in my scenario.  A user could search for "Item 125" and a description of "Item blue extra wide 125"  Would still need to match, But "item detail detail detail detail 25 detail"  would need to be thrown out.  I have an odd use case.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I have amended my post, the third condition is **not** superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Can we use the following rewritten query?

```
SELECT ID, Description, Date
FROM Item
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 MONTH)
AND MATCH (description) AGAINST ('"1 2 a 4" @30 +item' in boolean mode);
```

Proximity is slow because it's complicated. Suggest you use no more than two words for proximity search. As the word number increases, the query time increases more.